# table does not refresh after i press back and select another option. always the same table as the first selection

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, viewwillappear

I have a list of `Patient` objects in my main page, which is a table view. When I click on one of the rows, it will go to another page which shows two options pertaining to that particular patient, option 1 being "Patient Info", and option 2 being a list of all admission dates of the particular patient selected.

I have some trouble with the second option -- the table of admission dates does not seem to refresh when I return back to the main page and select another patient. The admission dates table always shows the the admission dates of the first patient which I have selected. I really do not know where is the mistake.

I used the `viewWillAppear` method because `viewDidLoad` seems to only be called once; I proved that using `NSLog(_nric);` -- it only prints once. I suspect it's the table view method which is giving me the problem. Can someone please give me some advice on my second method below?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    _listOfPatientsAdmInfoOptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



    for(PatientAdmInfo *patientAdmInfo1 in [[PatientDatabase database] patientAdminList:_nric]){

        [ _listOfPatientsAdmInfoOptions addObject:patientAdmInfo1];
        NSLog(_nric); 

    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    _patientAdmInfo = [[PatientAdmInfo alloc] init ];


    _patientAdmInfo = [_listOfPatientsAdmInfoOptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = _patientAdmInfo.pDiagnosis;
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = patientAdmInfo.pDiagnosis, patientAdmInfo.sDiagnosis;


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `reloadData` method on your table Instance after updating your array in - `(void)viewWillAppear:`.

```
[myTabelView reloadData];
```

And also not forget to call `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` in `viewWillAppear` method.

So your viewWillAppear method should be ..

-

```
(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    _listOfPatientsAdmInfoOptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



    for(PatientAdmInfo *patientAdmInfo1 in [[PatientDatabase database] patientAdminList:_nric]){

        [ _listOfPatientsAdmInfoOptions addObject:patientAdmInfo1];
        NSLog(_nric); 

    }
   [myTabelView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: @jhaliya thanks so much for the prompt reply.. i tried [myTableView reloadData]; but there is an error stating "unknown receiver myTableView" .... do you know what might b the problem? =(

Comment: Use the name of your UITabelView object  and also remove     `_patientAdmInfo = [[PatientAdmInfo alloc] init ];` it has nothing to do with code ..

Comment: sorry for being such a noob.. but i am really new here.. i did not declare any UITableView object... how do i go about finding the name of my UITableView object

Comment: What is the name of your base class of your view controller ?

Comment: thanks Jhaliya! i did this [self.tableVIew reloadData]; and it worked.. Thanks so much.. u r a life saver =)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `_patientAdmInfo` object is an instance variable. Every cell in your table is looking at the same object to get its data.  Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method should look like this:

```
PatientAdminInfo *tempPatient = [_listOfPatientsAdmInfoOptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = tempPatient.pDiagnosis;
```

this will ensure that every cell is looking at the appropriate PatientAdminInfo object.

Comment: .. thanks for the prompt reply. I did wa u said.. but the table is still populating the same information as before... any other clue wa might be wrong? =(